# Elements conjugate in profinite completion

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, profinite-groups

> **Problem.** Let $G$ be a residually finite group, and identify $G$ with its image under the canonical map to its profinite completion $\hat{G}$. Let $x,y \in G$. Prove that the following conditions are equivalents:
>
> (i) $x,y$ are conjugate in $\hat{G}$.
>
> (ii) the imagens of $x,y$ in $G/K$ are conjugate in $G/K$, for every normal subgroup $K$ of finite index in $G$.

I'm sure that I'm confusing about this problem, so I'd like some help.

We know that
$$\hat{G} = \varprojlim_{K \in I}G/K$$
where $I$ is a non-empty filter base of normal subgroups of finite index in $G$ and there is a continuous homomorphism $\varphi: G \to \hat{G}$ given by $\varphi(g) = Kg$. The pair $(\hat{G},\varphi)$ has the property:

*"if $\psi: G \to H$ is a continuous homomorphism, to a finite group $H$, then there is a unique homomorphism $\overline{\psi}: \hat{G} \to H$ such that $\psi = \overline{\psi}\circ\varphi$."*

1. If $x,y \in G$, then $Kx,Ky \in \hat{G}$. So, the item (i) must be  "... in $G$"?
2. Who are the imagens of $x,y$ in $G/K$? Since $\hat{G} = \varprojlim G/K$, then $(G/K_{i},f_{ij})$ is a inverse system with inverse limit $(\hat{G},f_{i})$ where $f_{i}: \hat{G} \to G/K_{i}$? We can connect $G$ to $\hat{G}$ by $\varphi$ and $\hat{G}$ to $G/K_{i}$ by $f_{i}$, but who is $f_{i}$? I don't know a definition of completion using, explicitly, inverse systems indexed by a direct set and its maps. Thus, I don't know how to start this problem.

Comment: $\hat{G}$ is the set of sequences $(a_K K)_{K \in I}$ (indexed by finite index normal subgroups $K$) such that $a_K \in G, a_K K\in  G/K$ and $a_K H = a_H H$ whenever $K\subset H$. Trying with $G = \Bbb{Z}$ and $I$ the index $p^n$ subgroups yields the $p$-adic integers, with $I$ every subgroup it is the profinite integers.

Comment: Just a word on your profile: if you're tackling problems like this, then, surely, you'll be able to help someone. Have confidence. You're doing well :)

Comment: @Shaun thank you for the encouragement!

Comment: You can also think to $\hat{G}$ as the set of (limits of) sequences $(g_n)_{n \ge 1}$ such that $g_n K$ ends being constant for every $K$, then $a,b\in G$ are conjugate in $\hat{G}$ if $a^{-1} (g_n  b g_n^{-1}) K \to K$ for every $K$.

Comment: @reuns think in $\hat{G}$ as the set of limits of sequences, does this have anything to do with Cauchy sequences? The word "completion" in Real Analysis is "equivalent" to convergence of Cauchy sequences.

Comment: $p$-adic integers $\Bbb{Z}_p$ are [the completion of $\Bbb{Z}$ for the $p$-adic metric](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3189472/how-would-one-explain-the-concept-of-a-p-adic-number-in-laymans-terms/3189551#3189551) $d(b,b+a) = |a|_p = p^{-k}$  if $a \equiv 0 \bmod p^k,a \not \equiv 0 \bmod p^{k+1}$. Do you see how an equivalent metric can be defined in any group $G$ to obtain $\hat{G}$ as the completion ?

Comment: The metric is $d(b,ab) = n^{-1}$ if $aK \ne K, |G/K|= n$ and $|G/H| < n \implies aH = H$

Comment: @reuns I still dont understand all the details, but I will check your example carefully. Seems very interesting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a "filter basis of normal subgroups" to define $\hat{G}$. Take $\hat{G}= \underset{\leftarrow}{\mathrm{lim}} \: G/K$ over every normal subgroup of finite index $K$ of $G$. Then $\hat{G}$ is a subgroup of the product $\prod_K G/K$ (over the same $K$'s) as in the comment by @reuns, and one has projections $p_K :\hat{G} \to G/K$ for every normal subgroup of finite index $K$ of $G$, that are factorizations of the common projections $\pi_K : G \to G/K$ : $\pi_K = G \overset{i}{\to} \hat{G} \overset{p_K}{\to} G/K$ (where $i$ is the natural inclusion).

So $(i) \Rightarrow (ii)$ is pretty clear.

For the other inclusion, you have to build an element $z=(z_K)_K \in \hat{G}$ such that $zxz^{-1}=y$ from $z_K$'s such that $z_K p_K(x) z_K^{-1}=p_K(y)$ for every normal subgroup of finite index $K$ of $G$.

Comment: I think I got your idea! I will try.

Comment: Actually you can keep the definition with a basis, you'll just need to recover any normal subgroup of finite index from the basis. It works the same way